# Next.js & Ant Design Dragger: File upload fails on deployed instance

Tags: file-upload, next.js, antd, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to build a file upload with Next.js and Ant Design using React.

On localhost, everything works fine. When I deployed the instance and try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
Request URL: https://my-app.my-team.now.sh/url/for/test/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 
Remote Address: 34.65.228.161:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

The UI that I use looks like the following:

```js
<Dragger {...fileUploadProps}>{renderImageUploadText()}</Dragger>
```

where `fileUploadProps` are:

```js
const fileUploadProps = {
  name: 'file',
  multiple: false,
  showUploadList: false,
  accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg',
  onChange(info) {
    const { status } = info.file;
    if (status === 'done') {
      if (info.file.size > 2000000) {
        setUploadSizeError('File size is too large');
      } else {
        handleFieldValue(API_FORM_FIELDS.PICTURE, info);
      }
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      setUploadSizeError(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },
};
```

I assume, it has to do with the server side rendering of Next.js? On the other hand, it might not, because by the time I navigated to `url/for/test` it should render on the client.

How do you implemented file uploads with Ant Design and Next.js?

Comment: I run into the same problem. Please post your solution here if you figured it out!

Answer (score 8):

Antd's [Upload component](https://ant.design/components/upload) requires the `action` prop, which is the URL for which to send data. If you don't need to send data to a url, you can make a no-op api route that simply returns a success, and then pointed Ant Design `<Upload>`'s `action` to `/api/noop`

```js
/* pages/api/noop.tsx */

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  res.status(200).end('noop')
}
```

```js
/* Wherever I'm using <Upload /> */

<Upload
  ...otherProps
  action={'/api/noop'}
>
```

Note: this is specific to Next.js, which makes it easy to create API routes.

Comment: This is a great way to deal with this. You might need to up the max body size tho. You can do this with the custom Config object -> https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config

Comment: Worked for me as well. Easy, clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

By default, the ANTD upload component makes a POST request to upload the file. So, to avoid this, add a customRequest props on Upload as below.

```js
customRequest={({ onSuccess }) => setTimeout(() => { onSuccess("ok", null); }, 0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Got this to work by passing the prop `action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"` to the `<Upload/>` component.

The ANTD Upload component must make a POST request to upload the file. It either makes that POST request to the current url, which results in the 405, or to the url specified by the `action` prop. https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76 works as this url.